# CSS subgrid doesn't show gap for row

Tags: css, css-grid, subgrid

I'm getting to know CSS' grid and subgrid. Working on a simple form with two columns and a few subgrids.

the parent grid has a gap: 1em - both te column and the row have show a 1em gap properly. But the subgrid shows only the gap for the column, the row gap does **not** work - it's 0. I can't figure out why...
I can give the subgrid a gap-row: 1em, that works. Buth I prefer to solve the *real* problem and thereby learning *what* causes the *real* problem in the first place.

The html and CSS:

```css
#gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-items: left;
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  justify-items: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="gridContainer">
  <div class="subgrid">
    <label for="nameCompanyDebt1">Naam onderneming:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameCompanyDebt1" name="nameCompanyDebt1">
    <label for="companyDebt1">Zakelijke schuld</label>
    <input type="text" id="companyDebt1" name="companyDebt1">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm aware that #gridContainer (the parent) does not have grid-template-rows. So there's no 'rows' to inherit. But gap: 1em counts for both the columns and rows, so that shouldn't be the issue, right?
I did try to add grid-template-rows to #gridContainer, but this only causes the rows to overlap/stack.

I'm also aware of the fact that the parent (#subGrid) is and ID, and the subgrid (.subgrid) is a class. It seems to be no problem, as the columns work fine as is.

Comment: What is the final design that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm creating an interactive form. The form ID also acts as a (main) grid. Depending on certain input, some parts must be added or removed. The parts that I want to show/hide,  are added to a div with a certain class. That way, I can simply hide (display: none) the class. Ofcourse this div is a child of the main grid, and therefore should act as a subgrid to keep its children in line with the main grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only subgriding the columns, so the entire subgrid fits inside the first row of the grid. So there is no gap to be displayed. To fix, subgrid the rows too.

Set `grid-row` to span as many rows as you've got in the subgrid.

```css
#gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-items: left;
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  justify-items: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="gridContainer">  
  <div class="subgrid">
    <label for="nameCompanyDebt1">Naam onderneming:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameCompanyDebt1" name="nameCompanyDebt1">
    <label for="companyDebt1">Zakelijke schuld</label>
    <input type="text" id="companyDebt1" name="companyDebt1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding the 'grid-row' doesn't really help, as I need it to add implicit rows with new children. 

Your answer did help me get my head around the concept of subgrid; I understand now that the subgrid is a grid in and of itself, and only inherits the column/gap and/or row/gap. I thought it would be an exact copy of its parent, which it does not. Only adding 'gap: 1em' is suffice for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had an epiphany! the soluton to my problem was not a div with `display: subgrid`, but a div has `diplay: contents`!

This way all the children act as a child of the primary grid, but I can hide the div (and all its children) via its ID.